# Trying to include a maven built library in Eclipse, giving missing artifact error

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, artifact

I've seen that there are quite a few questions regarding this problem, but unfortunately none have solved it for me. Here is a screencap of what's going on:

[image: pom.xml dependency error]

It is dependent on the android-support-v4 jar file which as you can see is added to my build path. It the exact jar file from the maven library directory's libs folder. I've tried the following:

- Restarting Eclipse
- Cleaning the project
- Right-clicking the project and updating dependencies
- Updating project configuration Disabling and re-enabling workspace resolution

Nothing has helped. Is there any other tricks to getting this resolved? All of the answer's I've seen suggest doing these things that I have already tried.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual root cause:

The [OP JMRboosties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588758/jmrboosties) reports in this instance having to **desactivate [Proguard](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html)** (the tool which shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names)

> disabling proguard on the line where the error occurred (the `<plugin>` item) in `pom.xml` solved the problem

(See "[How to use ProGuard with android-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ProGuard) ").

Certain side-effects can result from using Proguard: For example, the [Proguard page](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html) does mention:

> The default `proguard.cfg` file tries to cover general cases, but you might encounter exceptions such as `ClassNotFoundException`, which happens when ProGuard strips away an entire class that your application calls.

---

Original answer:

As mentioned in this [GitHub post](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/issues/40):

- you need to use [maven Android SDK Deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) to install it:

> I'm going to deploy my own android artifacts to my personal repository to avoid having this problem again.
> If you're not explicitly using Maven you can just import it as a regular Android project into eclipse and it'll pick up the `.jar` from the `libs/` directory.

(Note your `android-support-v4.jar` isn't in `libs` in your project)

- declare it in [your pom.xml](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/commit/b9ce16785aec8dd3ef1b5035c23da30bd1cc825e).

> **You have to install both Android 1.6 and the compat lib using the maven SDK deployer for now**.
>
> cd to `platforms/platform-4/` and `extras/compatibility-v4/` in the `deployer` and run `mvn install` in each.
>
> Hopefully the `compat` lib makes it into maven central soon so I can avoid this step.
>
> Again, the project is set up to be used as a normal Android project in eclipse too completely separate from maven.
> `File, New, Project, Android`, use `existing sources`, select `library/` folder.

Comment: Actually, disabling proguard on the line where the error occurred (the <plugin> item) in pom.xml solved the problem. There was no need to jump through all those hoops fortunately.

So to anyone who stumbles across this question: Don't be afraid to disable the proguard on the pom.xml, I tested it and it runs fine with no errors. I will answer the question with this in a bit, unless someone can come up with a more elegant solution.

Comment: @JMRboosties: good catch. I have included it in the answer for more visibility. If you still want to make a separate answer, I will remove my revision and put a link to your answer.

Comment: Your answer is more comprehensive, I will use this as the answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using m2e-android behind the scenes, the reason you're getting compile problems is that the m2e-android plug-in strips out all `provided` scope dependencies from the Eclipse project classpath.

We do this because, due to changes in ADT 16.0.0, any JAR file in the Eclipse classpath will be packaged into distributable APK file.